# Python elif not working as expected for string find

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to pull out the locations for an inconsistently formatted data field in a Pandas dataframe. (I do not maintain the data so I cannot alter how this field is formatted.)

Running the following toy version

```
string2 = 'Denver.John'
if string2.find(' -'):
    string2 = string2.split(' -')[0]
elif string2.find('.'):
    string2 = string2.split('.')[0]
print(string2)
```

gives me Denver.John instead of Denver. However, if I use an if instead:

```
string2 = 'Denver.John'
if string2.find(' -'):
    string2 = string2.split(' -')[0]
if string2.find('.'):
    string2 = string2.split('.')[0]
print(string2)
```

I get Denver, as desired. The problem is I also have strings like 'Las.Vegas - Rudy' and I want to be able to pull out Las.Vegas in those instances so I only want to split on a period if the field does not contain the hyphen (' - ').

Why does the elif not work for Denver.John?

Answer (score 2):

Because `find` either yields the index or `-1` while `-1` is valid!!!, so try using:

```
string2 = 'Denver.John'
if string2.find(' -') + 1:
    string2 = string2.split(' -')[0]
elif string2.find('.') + 1:
    string2 = string2.split('.')[0]
print(string2)
```

Or better like:

```
string2 = 'Denver.John'
if ' -' in string2:
    string2 = string2.split(' -')[0]
elif '.' in string2:
    string2 = string2.split('.')[0]
print(string2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that, this fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes I will, I can't for another 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
if ' -' in string2
```

instead. The find method returns an int

Answer (score 1):

`find()` returns the lowest index of the substring if it is found in given string. If it’s not found then it returns -1.

So in your case:

```
string2 = 'Denver.John'
print(string2.find(' -')) # prints -1
print(string2.find('.')) # prints 6
if string2.find(' -'):
    string2 = string2.split(' -')[0]
elif string2.find('.'):
    string2 = string2.split('.')[0]
print(string2)
```

So in your `if` statement you can compare the result of `find` with `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

string.find returns a position of the substring, and it is -1 if it doesn't find the substring.

Thus, do the following instead:

```
string2 = 'Denver.John'
if string2.find(' -') >= 0:
    string2 = string2.split(' -')[0]
elif string2.find('.') >= 0:
    string2 = string2.split('.')[0]
print(string2)
```